# Add column with condition in laravel update query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want update set of columns in which I have some conditions as if some values are empty then don't update that column.

```
$data = DB::connection('server')->table ('l AS l')
    ->join('lc AS lc', 'l.id', '=', 'lc.id_c')
    ->where('l.id', '=', $input['ass_l_id'])
    ->where('l.status', '=', $input['ass_l_s'])
    ->update(
      [
        'l.ass_user' => $input['user'],
        'l.ref_by' => $input['ref_by'],
        'lc.phone_number' => $input['mobile_no']
      ]
    );
```

above query works fine but I need to add condition as if ref_by is set or not empty then include else exclude, same for phone_number.
How can I achieve this. I tried raw query also like

```
$sql = "UPDATE l AS l JOIN lc AS lc ON l.id = lc.id_c SET l.ass_user = '".$input['user'] ."'";
            if(isset($input['ref_by']) && $input['ref_by'] != '') {
                $sql.= " , 'l.ref_by' = '".$input['ref_by']."'";
            }
            if(isset($input['mobile_no']) && $input['mobile_no'] != '') {
                $sql.= " , 'lc.phone_number' = '".$input['mobile_no']."'";
            }
            
            $sql.= " WHERE l.id = '". $input['ass_l_id'] ."' AND l.status = '".$input['ass_l_s']."'";

$data = DB::connection('server')->raw($sql);
```

But above query doesn't update the columns.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update method take an array as argument that represent the columns you want to update and their values ...

build it your self then pass it ...

```
$updateFields=[];
if(isset($input['ref_by']) && $input['ref_by'] != '') {
              $updateFields['l.ref_by']= $input['ref_by'];
            }
 if(isset($input['mobile_no']) && $input['mobile_no'] != '') {
               $updateFields['l.phone_number']= $input['mobile_no'];
            }
$updateFields['l.ass_user']=  $input['user'];



$data = DB::connection('server')->table ('l AS l')
    ->join('lc AS lc', 'l.id', '=', 'lc.id_c')
    ->where('l.id', '=', $input['ass_l_id'])
    ->where('l.status', '=', $input['ass_l_s'])
    ->update($updateFields);
```

Comment: Thanks I was not aware how can I create update array. :)